# Javascript variable declaration, accept a value from a field if the field is present, if not assign a preset value

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here in the below code, some rows has this nested field with value present and some doesn't. So I am trying to declare it with the value if the field is present, if not I want to assign 'false' in it. I tried using the double pipe operator to handle this situation, but the below code doesn't run at all.

```
let penetration = result[i].address_stats[1].penetration || false;
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```js
let penetration = result[i]?.address_stats[1]?.penetration || false;
```

You could also do something like this:

```
let penetration = false;
if ( result
  && result[i]
  && result[i].address_stats
  && result[i].address_stats[1]
  && result[i].address_stats[1].penetration ) {
    penetration = result[i].address_stats[1].penetration;
}
```

Not all of those checks may be necessary, I just included them all since I'm not sure what `result` looks like.

Comment: Thanks Jon, the optional chaining didn't work, it says 'This experimental syntax requires enabling the parser plugin: 'optionalChaining''

Comment: I'm assuming you're transpiling with babel? Add this to your plugins array in your .babelrc file: `"@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"`

Comment: This is a component js file in salesforce, I cant find the plugins array, or maybe I am looking at the wrong location.

Comment: Added an alternative method for you to use

Comment: Your alternative idea worked, All I was doing so far was the final check. I should I have done the it dot by dot. Thanks Jon for the effort taken.

Answer (score 1):

```
   let penetration =false
   if(!result[i].address_stats[1].penetration)
   { 
     penetration = result[i].address_stats[1].penetration
   }

   //Optionally
   penetration=result[i].address_stats[1].penetration?result[i].address_stats[1].penetration:false
```

Comment: Thanks Ankush, didn't work, I don't see any errors, but the code doesn't run.

Comment: oops,I forgot the Bang(!) operator.

Comment: Hello Ankush, Yours will work. But I should do a check on the first dot section before the second. Thats what I was doing wrong all the time.

Comment: It's like saying `undefined?undefined:false` (if value doesn't get returned) , which returns `false`